# Why does the Spring Autowire stops working when I add the "RunWith" annotation?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, powermock

Once I add the `RunWith` annotation, that is `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` the Spring Autowire does not work anymore!

```
class B {  
  @Autowire  
  SessionFactory session;
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)  
@PrepareForTest{SomeClass.class}

class Testing {  

  @Test
  methodA(){  
    //mehod 
  }

  @Test
  methodD(){  
  }    
}
```

Now, method A makes a call to class B, but due to `RunWith(PowerMockRunner)` annotation, the Autowiring is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the 'before' case look like.  @Autowire doesn't just work.  Were you using some Spring test runner or MockitoJUnitRunner or something else when it was working before?

Comment: Instead of auto wiring, use Whitebox or setters to set the field to a mock. You get more control of what's happening in your class that way.

Comment: hi jhericks, when it was running, the RunWith said RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)

Answer (score 12):

In 2016 you can use runner delegate with PowerMockito, effectively using two runners:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

More details here: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/JUnit_Delegating_Runner

Answer (score 2):

Spring is not magic (even if it seems like it sometimes). No where in your code are you giving spring a chance to start up an application context and do its work of auto wiring your beans. You need to either start the context yourself or switch your test to use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. Unfortunately JUnit only supports a single runner at a time so you'll need to stop using the PowerMockRunner then.